# Event not firing through AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, .net-remoting

I am having a lot of trouble with AppDomains. I currently have an AppDomain containing camera controls, and am trying to have events raised from this secondary AppDomain (like a picture being taken) come back to the main program. Everything seems to be set up correctly (events are registered, functions will run across domain boundry) but when I try to invoke, nothing happens. Everything I can find on the subject involves exceptions being raised rather than just nothing happening at all.

I don't know how much better I can explain it than this, so I made a (very simplistic) diagram, and can post any code that is necessary.

http://a.imageshack.us/img832/8205/cameradiagram.png

A breakpoint fires in the `OnPictureUpdated.Invoke(pic);` portion, inside the secondary AppDomain, but nothing (either inside `CameraContainer` or in the main application is raised. I am doing a null check when invoking events, I just didn't put that in the diagram.

Comment: What is the base type of CameraContainer?

Comment: @JaredPar Object; it isn't inheriting anything.

Comment: Please read my blog on cross-AppDomain Communication https://blog.vcillusion.co.in/sending-events-through-application-domain-boundary/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+1 for the effort in the question.

I believe this may just be because your `CameraContainer` isn't a `MarshalByRefObject`. Because it's attaching to the event, the `AppDomain` containing the `CameraManager` effectively needs to call back into the primary `AppDomain` when the event is raised.

Comment: This seems to have solved it! Glad it was something simple. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the `CameraContainer` is triggered within the primary appdomain? Because I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Please read my blog on cross-AppDomain Communication https://blog.vcillusion.co.in/sending-events-through-application-domain-boundary/